# How to distinguish selected row from current row in TableView in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx, tableview

If display simple TableView sample, then select first row, then press `Ctrl` and then `Down Arrow` button two times, we will see the following picture:

[image]

I.e. first row remains selected, while third row get cursor.

How to know this row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the focused row. You can access that row via the [`focusModel` property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#focusModelProperty):

```
int rowIndex = tableView.getFocusModel().getFocusedIndex();
```

The [`TableView.TableViewFocusModel` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.TableViewFocusModel.html) used for `focusModel` also supports some additional features like accessing the item for the focused row.

Comment: I don't see how to listen `focusedIndexProperty()`?

Comment: By adding a listener??? I don't see the problem. Usually the `focusModel` isn't swapped, but if you plan to do so, add a listener that adds/removes a listener to the model, should it be changed.

Comment: There is no `focusedIndexProperty()` to add listener to

Comment: I accidentally added `getFocusModel()` twice to the code snippet; fixed that now. The `focusedIndex` property can be found in the superclass of `TableView.TableViewFocusModel` right here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/FocusModel.html#focusedIndexProperty